# Getting Position.Y of parent node with physicsBodies

Tags: sprite-kit

Im trying to see when my circleGroup Class Object has left the screen
(am pretty new at this so any suggestions welcome!)
including any other way to remove the class once it is off screen

circleGroup Class contains a blank SKSpriteNode, and 8 other sprites are grouped around the blank SKSpriteNode as children (these have physics),

Gamelayer:

**Always logs (0,0)**

```
 NSLog(@"_mycircleGroup.position.y @%f",_mycircleGroup.position.y);
 //outputs myArc.position.y @0.000000
```

which means I can't check when Class is off screen

```
if (_mycircleGroup.position.y < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"_mycircleGroup off screen");
        //[_mycircleGroup removeFromParent];
        //[self myMethod];
    }
```

Any ideas how I might read position?

with thanks
:)

**Solution**, 
I needed to be logging the parent node inside of the class
so in this case I have a class and in it is a parent sprite which i need to track (Since it seems like nodes with physics don't track)

```
if (self.myCircleClass.parentSpriteThatEveryThingIsAddedTo.position.y < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"my arc off screen");
        //[twoSpritesWithParticlesBridge removeFromParent];
        //[self addStaticLinkedSpriteWithParticles];
    }
```

Comment: Probably you can go with intersectsNode method https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/intersectsNode: and combination with calculateAccumualtedFrame. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/calculateAccumulatedFrame About (0,0) issue... If myArc is child of a circleGroup, then myArc probably never moves...It is probably just added to circleGroup, and circleGroup is moving, but myArc stays at its position in parents coordinate system.

Comment: hmm thats for links am about to go read up,
_mycircleGroup.position.y is the entire class (not the children) - but is the class loaded into the game layer, so, yep not sure why I cant read the location...ill try post code later, thanks xox

Comment: Why does parent's node position always log (0, 0)? Can we reproduce this issue?

Comment: @WangYudong thanks was enough of a lead, indeed I had only been checking the Class and not actually the parent node (Its my first week of making my own classes) thankyou, you jogged the brain cells, 
you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

As above with thanks to  WangYudong for jogging my logic :P

**Solution**, I needed to be logging the parent node inside of the Class so in this case I have a class and in it is a parent sprite which I need to track (Since it seems like nodes with physics don't track, so I couldn't track te entire object, just the object without physics...)

```
if (self.myCircleClass.parentSpriteThatAllOtherSpritesParentedTo.position.y < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"my arc off screen");
        //[twoSpritesWithParticlesBridge removeFromParent];
        //[self addStaticLinkedSpriteWithParticles];
    }
```

Take everything with a pinch of salt, non definite and completely questionable! (since I'm new at coding), but hope it helps someone :)